# Terraform - GCP VM - provision Multiple VMs with Multiple extra disks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I am trying to create Multiple VMs with few Extra Disks. I gave 2 extra disks and want to create 2 VMs. it seems the extra disk created only for one vm and not for another one vm and it throws that extra disk name already exists.

```
Error: Error creating instance: googleapi: Error 400: The disk resource 'projects/xxxxxxx/zones/us-central1-a/disks/extra-disk-1-ab23e8823b41ac18' is already being used by 'projects/xxxxxxx/zones/us-central1-a/instances/xxxxxx', resourceInUseByAnotherResource
│ 
│   with module.compute_vm.google_compute_instance.vm_instance[1],
│   on ../../main.tf line 66, in resource "google_compute_instance" "vm_instance":
│   66: resource "google_compute_instance" "vm_instance" {
```

Main.tf in examples folder (calling module)

```
module "compute_vm" {
  source              = "../../"
  num_instances       = 2
  boot_disk_size_gb   = "10"
  disk2_type          = "pd-ssd"
  os_distro           = "ubuntu"
  extra_disks = [{ name = "extra-disk-1", disk2_size_gb = "16" }, { name = "extra-disk-2", disk2_size_gb = "15" }]
}
```

in module Main.tf

```
resource "google_compute_disk" "disk2" {
  project = var.project_id
  count   = length(var.extra_disks)
  name    = "${var.extra_disks[count.index].name}-${random_id.instance_id.hex}"
  type    = var.disk2_type
  size    = var.extra_disks[count.index].disk2_size_gb
  zone    = var.zone
  labels = {
    environment = var.environment
  }
}

resource "random_id" "instance_id" {
  byte_length = 8
}

resource "google_compute_instance" "vm_instance" {
  project      = var.gcp_project_id
  count        = var.num_instances
  name         = "vm-${random_id.instance_id.hex}-${count.index + 1}"
  machine_type = var.machine_type
  zone         = var.zone

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = lookup(var.image, var.os_distro)
      size  = var.boot_disk_size_gb
    }
  }

  dynamic "attached_disk" {
    for_each = google_compute_disk.disk2
    content {
      source      = attached_disk.value.self_link
      device_name = attached_disk.value.name
    }
  }
  # attached_disk {
  #   source      = element(google_compute_disk.disk2.*.self_link, count.index)
  #   device_name = element(google_compute_disk.disk2.*.name, count.index)
  # }

  network_interface {
    subnetwork = data.google_compute_subnetwork.subnet.self_link
    network_ip = element(google_compute_address.static.*.address, count.index)
  }

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [attached_disk]
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gopalakrishnan answering this for rest of the community.

###### Why is this happening?

Count in vm_instance is based on var.num_instances while count on disks is based on var.extra_disks. 1st VM will be attached with extra_disks as part of the config, 2nd VM will also try to attach the same disks but will fail because those disks are already attached to VM1.

###### What we need to do? :

We need to make sure that for every instance created new disks are created and attached to the instance rather than reusing the same disks.

###### How do we do it? (One of the ways)

1. Remove the count variable from `google_compute_instance` block.
2. Call this terraform code as a module from another folder. [[Creating a terraform module]](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/modules/develop/structure.html)
3. Use count in modules to create multiple VMs with multiple disks in them.

###### Other ways :

- Making the count in `google_compute_disk` = Number of disks needed * Number of VMs and including a logic to call specific elements of `google_compute_disk.disk2` in `google_compute_instance`  based on count.index of VM being created.

Comment: Hello - I used ```Count=<num>``` in example module, it works fine. but the problem is here I have my local provider and we need to feed some values as variable in provider block. So, we force in root main.tf file.d to use

```Error: Module module.compute_vm contains provider configuration Providers cannot be configured within modules using count, for_each or depends_on.```

Here is the provider block that has to use in root main.tf
```provider "testprovkider" {
  service_account = var.sa
  pnumber  = var.projnum
}```

Please provide your assistance. Thanks!!

Comment: apology, I should have clearly mention that.. its for extra disk partition and not the boot disk.